# How to add multiple image in opencart 2.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart2.x

I have creating a option call small. In that option i want to add multiple image. My query is how can i assign a name for `hidden text`

Here i have already did one functionality in `addOptionValue` function create button

```
function addOptionValue(option_row)
{
  some code here
 html += '  <td class="text-right" id="multi-image'+ option_value_row +'"><a href="" id="thumb-image' + option_value_row + '"data-toggle="image" class="img-thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" alt="" title="" data-placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" /></a><input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_row + '][product_option_value][' + option_value_row + '][image_option][' + option_value_row + '][inner_image]" value="" id="input-image' + option_value_row + '" /><button id="add-image'+option_value_row+'" type="button" onclick="addOptionImage('+option_value_row+');" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_option_value_add; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>';
}
```

[image]

```
<script>
      var image_row = <?php echo $image_row; ?>;
      function addOptionImage(image_row)
      {

        var html = '<a href="" id="thumb-image' + image_value_row + '"data-toggle="image" class="img-thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" alt="" title="" data-placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" /></a>'; 

        html +='<input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + image_row + '][product_option_value][' + image_row + '][image_option][' + image_row + '][inner_image]" value="" id="input-image' + image_value_row + '" />';

       $('#multi-image'+image_row+'').append(html);

       image_row++;

      }
    </script>
```

Here how can i store this multiple images? please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

I have creating a same module in  Opencart 2.3.

Please see my following code:

```
<script>

var image_row = <?php echo $image_row; ?>;
var image_rows = "";
function addOptionImage(option_value_row,image_row)
{
  var child = $(".multi_image"+image_row).length;
  var html = '<div class="row text-center"><a href="" id="thumb-image'+ image_row +'' + image_row + '' + child + '"data-toggle="image" class="img-thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" alt="" title="" style="width: 50px;" data-placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" /></a>&nbsp;';

  html +='<input type="hidden" name="product_option[' + option_value_row + '][product_option_value][' + image_row + '][image_option][' + child + '][inner_image]" value="" id="input-image'+ image_row +'' + image_row + '' + child + '" class="multi_image'+image_row+'" />';

  html += '<button type="button" onclick="$(this).tooltip(\'destroy\');$(\'#thumb-image'+ image_row +''+ image_row +'' + child + '\').remove();$(\'#input-image'+ image_row +''+ image_row +'' + child + '\').remove();$(\'#btn-remove'+ image_row +''+ image_row +'' + child + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-remove'+ image_row +'' + image_row +''+ child + '"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></div>';

  $('#multi-image'+image_row+'').append(html);
 // console.log(image_row);
  image_row++;
  image_rows++;

}
//console.log(image_rows);
</script>
```

And use `imploded` and `explode` to store the image value in `database`.